# How get data in Symfony2 from android's post method

Tags: php, android, symfony, http-post

I have an android app which makes a post function sending data to a Symfony project. Then I want to get these data and storage in my bd. I think the problem is in my php code and not in android's. I have tried in a lot of ways but with no result.

My android's post function:

```
public String sendPost(String username, String password, String email, String city) {

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://192.168.1.120/TortillatorAPI/web/new_user");
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try 
    {   
       List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
       params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", city));
       httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
       response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {

    }
    return response.toString();
}
```

The routing for a new user:

```
new_user:
    pattern: /new_user
    defaults: { _controller:TortillatorAPITortillatorBundle:Default:newUser}
```

And my Symfony function in my controller:

```
public function newUserAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $user = new User();
    $user->setUsername($request->get('username'));
    $user->setPassword($request->get('password'));
    $user->setEmail($request->get('email'));
    $user->setCity($request->get('city'));

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();

    $response = new Response();
    $response->setStatusCode(201);
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: What happens? any errors?

Comment: getRequest is deprecated though.

Comment: When I execute my android function it doesn't get back a response so it doesn't happen nothing

Answer (score 3):

Just some Errors i saw, which are too big for a comment:

Change this part:

And my Symfony function in my controller:

```
public function newUserAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $user = new User();
    $user->setUsername($request->get('username'));
    $user->setPassword($request->get('password'));
    $user->setEmail($request->get('email'));
    $user->setCity($request->get('city'));

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();

    $response = new Response();
    $response->setStatusCode(201);
    return $response;
}
```

into this, if your using annotations, otherwise you have to specify routing and method differently, aswell I've changed the Request Object.:

```
/**
*@Route("YOURROUTE", name="YOURROUTE")
*@Method("POST")
*@Template()
*/
public function newUserAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->setUsername($request->get('username'));
    $user->setPassword($request->get('password'));
    $user->setEmail($request->get('email'));
    $user->setCity($request->get('city'));

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();

    $response = new Response();
    $response->setStatusCode(201);
    return $response;
}
```